# Blockdata clearing chest instead of putting item in chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to put a wet sponge in a chest with the following command:

```
/blockdata -190 56 -401 {Items:[:{Count:1,Slot:4,id:sponge:1}]}
```

The `sponge:1` should give me a wet sponge, but instead it just clears the chest.

How can I put a wet sponge in a chest?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to /give user

Comment: no because that gives it to a user!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NBT data *(nor anywhere else in Minecraft)* you do not use `id:metadata` to get a block/item with a certain damage value.

The correct NBT item structure can be found here:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_Format#Item_structure

So, for your command, you should do:

```
blockdata -190 56 -401 {Items:[{Count:1,Slot:4,Damage:1,id:sponge}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add it to the chest without overwriting its existing contents, your only option is to temporarily create a hopper that will feed the chest. Unfortunately there isn't a way to add or remove individual elements in a list tag, such as item stacks in a container, using /blockdata.